# sum over partition

Tags: sql

The following query bring the correct value for totalqty. however it leaves or misses counting the qty for some items, why?

```
        SELECT
         PRODID, ITEMDES, QTY,  SUM(QTY) over (partition by prodId)  as totalqty, StockCode,shipName, shipCompany, shipAddress1, shipAddress2, shipAddress3,shipPostCode,shipcity,shipCountry,shipCounty,customerMessage
         FROM orderedItems oi
        left join orders o on oi.order_id = o.order_id
        WHERE prodId = prodId
        AND o.status = 'transaction authorised'
        AND o.delTime = '#FORM.delDateselect#'


            Group by PRODID,ITEMDES,QTY, StockCode,shipName, shipCompany, shipAddress1, shipAddress2, shipAddress3,shipPostCode,shipcity,shipCountry,shipCounty,customerMessage

            ORDER BY PRODID
```

Comment: By the look of it you are not using group by correctly, whenever I see queries with 5 or more group by fields its an indication that its wrong and although you may get the right results - it will bite you down the road.

Comment: Why are you doing a group by?  What is this query supposed to produce?

Comment: I want a list of all the orders and a total qty of the product i need above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `where` clause makes the `left outer join` behave like an `inner join`. Change it like this:

```
WHERE
    prodId = prodId and
    (
        o.order_id is null or 
        (
            o.status = 'transaction authorised' AND
            o.delTime = '#FORM.delDateselect#'
        )
    )
```

The reason is that if there is no matching order in `orders` `o.status` will be `NULL` and thus not equal to `'transaction authorised'`.

Furthermore, you don't need the group by. You already have the analytical function that does the `SUM` for you.